# Convert Pandas Series to Categorical

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Panda series 'ids' of only unique ids, which is a dtype of object.

```
data_df.id.dtype
```

returns dtype('O')

I'm trying to follow the example here to create a sparse matrix from my df: [Efficiently create sparse pivot tables in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661604/efficiently-create-sparse-pivot-tables-in-pandas/31679396)

```
id_u= list(data_df.id.unique())
row = data_df.id.astype('category', categories=reviewer_u).cat.codes
```

and I get:

```
TypeError: data type "category" not understood
```

I'm not sure what this error means and I haven't been able to find much on it.

Comment: Try `row = pd.Categorical(data_df['id'], categories=reviewer_u)` instead?

Comment: Related: [Pandas: convert categories to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38088652/pandas-convert-categories-to-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try instead:

```
row = pd.Categorical(data_df['id'], categories=reviewer_u)
```

You can get the codes using:

```
row.codes
```